# Is it wrong to say that the medium of a photon is his electromagnetic field?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, electromagnetism, particle-physics, quantum-electrodynamics

Without any air there can't be any soundwaves propagating because the air is the medium for soundwaves. Analogous a photon can't propagate without a EM-field because a photon is the vibration of this field. So can the field be the medium? And perhaps it would be possible for all particles and their fields?

If not why not?

Sean Carroll explaining that fields are real: 1:28:12
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gEKSpZPByD0

Comment: you have rediscovered QFT, if I follow you correctly......https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_field_theory....QFT treats particles as excited states of the underlying physical field, so these are called field quanta.

Comment: If there is an important distinction, whether purely mathematical or physical, to be made between treating the field as an operator as opposed  to thinking of it as a "carrier" or a "potential" (for want of  better words from someone who has barely any knowledge of QFT), I would appreciate a reference to a link that sets out how a field should be treated/viewed. If this question is unclear/mangled, please ignore it.

Comment: @CountTo10, I think I know roughly what you're asking.  While the following isn't entirely clear to me, I believe it is the case that there is the quantum (operator valued) field, e.g., $\phi(x)$, governed by some equation of motion *and* there is a stateful entity for which there is a vacuum (no excitation) state $|0\rangle$, $n$ quanta states, and superpositions all living in a Fock space (for a free field at least).  As for a link, try [There are no particles, only fields](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1204.4616).

Comment: @CountTo10, for example, here's a quote from the link:  *"But what does the operator field Eq. (3) operate on? Just as in NRQP, operators operate on the system's quantum state |Ψ>. But the Hilbert space for such states cannot have the same structure as for the single-body Schroedinger equation, or even its N-body analog, because N must be allowed to vary in order to describe creation and destruction of quanta. So the radiation field's quantum states exist in a Hilbert space of variable N called "Fock space.""*

Comment: @AlfredCentauri  I honestly just about  know what I am asking for  myself, but I do want to put bits and pieces that I do  know into a coherent picture.  I am going to give it a few years to learn and sink in.  I am very grateful for the link and your answer.

Comment: There is also the possibility that fields are made of billions of  photons oscillating at different frequencies and if coherent would resemble a waves. Any  phenomena of light can be derived from a particle bases.

Comment: See this link on how classical fields are built up from quntum mechanical  formulation  , using QFT http://motls.blogspot.com/2011/11/how-classical-fields-particles-emerge.html

Comment: But the author is so convinced that his biased would never allow him to consider or even imagine alternate ideas. There are derivations that work and are much simpler than what he proposes.

Answer (score 1):

When you deal with photons, you have to think that, as countTo10 said, they are excited states of the electromagnetic field. So what actually propagates in the space is the EM field, while photons are "delocalized over all the space covered by the field. As an example, think of a 1D standing wave, the frequency of which is $\nu$: given the boundary condition for $\vec E$, $\vec E(x=0,t)=\vec E(x=L,t)=0$, you can say that the wave exists only in the region of space between 0 and L. This means that the photons of frequency $\nu$ are not localized in some point x, instead the are spread over all the region of space from 0 to L. In analogy, a travelling EM wave, the photons are delocalized over all of the wave, thus it's misleading talking about their propagation.

EDIT

You can think of the EM field as an "entity" that exists even in the absence of charges that can produce EM waves.Now,if an EM wave is produced, it certainly carries some amount of energy, so it is propagated in the space; but when you give a quantum mechanical description of electromagnetism, you deal with photons, that are *quanta of energy*. They don't "exist" in the real space, but are particles existing in the so-called Foch-space, that is introduced in the second quantization. Notice that actually the quantity that you can measure are the electric and magnetic field, not the number of photons, and that the EM wave is not the wave function of the photons. This is because photons arise when you can notice that the electric and magnetic fields oscilattion are **formally** equivalent to the position-momentum coordinates of an armonic oscillator. Thus the photons are the quanta of energy derivable from an hamiltonian proper of a quantum mechanical armonic oscillator of position $\hat q \propto \hat E$ and momentum $ \hat p \propto \hat H $. But these coordinates are not real positions and momenta, they just are formally idantical. In this sense the photons are not moving in the real space.

Comment: It seems that you say that the excited state as a photon is, is equal to the whole EM field. But couldn't the EMfield be more than the excited EMfield of a particle?

Comment: Is the Foch space the same space where virtual photons 'live'?

Comment: Yes, they can be thought as fluctuation of the vacuum state.